# How to implement @ManyToMany mapping correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, many-to-many, relational-database

I don't understand, should Hibernate work automatically or not?

I have `Category` entity which is coded following:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
public String Url;

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "category_childs")
private Set<Category> childs = new HashSet<Category>();

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "category_parents")
private Set<Category> parents = new HashSet<Category>();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

public String Title;

public boolean Done;
```

This causes the following table created

```
CREATE TABLE
category_parents
(
    Category_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parents_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Category_Url, parents_Url),
    CONSTRAINT FK9BB292C83275D6D7 FOREIGN KEY (Category_Url) REFERENCES category (Url) ,
    CONSTRAINT FK9BB292C8569C2962 FOREIGN KEY (parents_Url) REFERENCES category (Url),
    CONSTRAINT parents_Url UNIQUE (parents_Url),
```

which is incorrect since `parents_Url` should not be unique (multiple rows should be allowed to have same parent).

If I code without @JoinTable specification

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
public String Url;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
//@JoinTable(name = "category_childs")
private Set<Category> childs = new HashSet<Category>();

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
//@JoinTable(name = "category_parents")
private Set<Category> parents = new HashSet<Category>();

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();

public String Title;

public boolean Done;
```

then I will have the following

```
CREATE TABLE
category_category
(
    Category_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parents_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    childs_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Category_Url, childs_Url),
    CONSTRAINT FK8635931F3275D6D7 FOREIGN KEY (Category_Url) REFERENCES category (Url) ,
    CONSTRAINT FK8635931F569C2962 FOREIGN KEY (parents_Url) REFERENCES category (Url) ,
    CONSTRAINT FK8635931F6ADF3430 FOREIGN KEY (childs_Url) REFERENCES category (Url),
```

How to make Hibernate to create relation table with TWO fields?

like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE
category_category
(
    parents_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    childs_Url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (parents_Url, childs_Url),
    CONSTRAINT FK8635931F569C2962 FOREIGN KEY (parents_Url) REFERENCES category (Url) ,
    CONSTRAINT FK8635931F6ADF3430 FOREIGN KEY (childs_Url) REFERENCES category (Url),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate creates an unique column in the first case because you are using `@OneToMany` which tells hibernate that a category have at most one parent. In your code where you commented out `@JoinTable` you also changed `@OneToMany` to `@ManyToMany`. That's why hibernate doesn't create an unique constraint in this case.

I suppose that the category's childs have the category itself as a parent. In that case either childs or parents must be defined as the other side of the relation by using `mappedBy` in `@ManyToMany`:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "category_childs")
private Set<Category> childs = new HashSet<Category>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="childs")
private Set<Category> parents = new HashSet<Category>();
```